# Yii2 - how to deal with similar routes

Tags: yii, yii2

I have following routes:

```
'http://' . $domain . '/community-board/<topicName:\w+(-\w+)>/<id:\d+>' => 'board-posts/index',
'http://' . $domain . '/community-board/<topicName:\w+(-\w+)>/<postName:\w+(-\w+)><id:\d+>' => 'board-posts/view',
```

The first routing is always fired, and I can't access the second route. Is there a way in yii to deal with this?

Comment: Give me please exampes of URL, that resolved by first rule. How you define that has been resolved certain rule?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can drop `http://' . $domain . '/` unless you want to leave this rules active only for a specific domain.

I see probable mistake in the second rule. Route `community-board/topic-main/post-SO-question39163975` will be parsed as follows:

`['topicName' => 'main', 'postName' => 'SO-question3916397', 'id' => 5]`

I'd suggest to modify the regular expression in the second rule as follows:
`community-board/<topicName:\w+(-\w+)>/<postName:\w+(-\w+?)><id:\d+>` (added `?` to postName property to make RegExp lazy). After the change:

`['topicName' => 'main', 'postName' => 'SO-question', 'id' => 39163975]`

I've checker rules and can't see any other problems.